# Limit inbound bandwidth on Live Streaming Linux

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, streaming, video-streaming

I'm new about servers and I'm working on a platform to streaming live events to an app and a webpage (The idea is to create a local YouTube on my country, Angola). Talking with my friends he warned me that to have a good enought live streaming I have to limit my users bandwidth on delivering streaming on my server.

For an example: He said that if my users has an internet speed of 4 Mbps, I have limit bandwidth inbound on my server to 2 Mbps.

So, I made some search about that and I figure out that for some realities, in my case Angola the internet upload is sucks, I have to set up a configurations to performing a good delivering streaming on real time.

My question is: How can I set up a configuration on my server for my users can live streaming for some quality if they have less than 1 Mbps for upload? I'm using Wowza Streaming Engine software with AWS EC2 instance with 16GB RAM, for now.

P.S: Sorry my english, I know its not good enought but I hope you guys understood me

Comment: Inbound when looking from what system? It's easier to limit *outbound* traffic (it's then just not sent on the wire). It's more difficult to limit inbound traffic, because even if you ignore it, it's  still clogging your bandwidth before you can do anything about it.

Comment: @A.B, I see, but is it possible? How?